# old YAZAKI PCB pins

Tags: pcb, pins

I have a circuit board out of an old dozer that are not manufactured any more. I managed to have a new one printed up as my first PCB project and it works great but I soldered wires to the new board as I couldn't identify the plug. The original board has connector pins crimped into the PCB and soldered on top layer. The importer has asked if I can supply a few boards for them so I have spent hours and hours searching around but couldn't find any pins or connectors close. Are there any suggestions of what they may be or where to look? Pins are spaced 6mm apart and are 2.5mm in diameter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So consider 1) making pins or 2) adapting to a new plug...

Comment: Can you get a photo of the socket?

Answer (score 0):

Mill-Max make PCB mount pins in various forms (press fit, solder fit, etc.).

[Mill-Max PCB mount pin](https://www.mill-max.com/products/printed-circuit-board-pcb-pin/solder-mount-pcb-pin/4914)

The biggest one I can find on their site is 2.03mm dia, which is probably going to be loose in the receptacle that's fitted to the other side.

But it's perhaps worth getting in touch with them, they do custom parts and it feels pretty trivial for them to make the pins you want - it'll cost $$$ though.

A slightly different approach would be to rewire the loom to use an obtainable connector with appropriate ratings and then respin you PCB to accept the mating part.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that in my own unit but was hopeful on finding a pin I could use to allow the importers of this dozer to just plug it in. The site suggested by Spehro is amazing. I have emailed and will post the outcome. Looks like they have a straight pin that would suit but wont have a flange to make sure they sit all the same. Might 3d print a holder to use to get then correct height before solder.

Comment: Brilliant, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you contact [Bead Electronics](https://www.beadelectronics.com/products/hollow-pin-product) in Connecticut USA. They make hollow pins like those shown in the image using a similar process as that used to make bead chains like inside a toilet pull mechanism or pull light switch.

[image]

There may be a prohibitive minimum quantity for your application, but many years ago I found them to be a good supplier.

Pins in the [octal base](https://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/Octal_base#/media/File:Octal_base.gif) originally used for vacuum tubes in the 1930s, but even today (and not that rarely) used for some industrial applications has a larger diameter of pin- 2.362mm so extracting those is probably not an option unless the mating sockets are quite compliant.