Identification of a directly soldered PCB terminal pin 13.55 mm × 1.58 mm
I add in this question the picture of a PCB terminal, in this picture have the mesures of it. somebody can tell to me what terminal is it?
Thanks.


PCI? As in PCI Bus? Please show a picture of the whole board as well

This terminal are soldered direct on the PCB.

Please show a picture of the whole PCB as well

It might help if you also showed us what they connect to.

It's unlikely you'll be able to find the exact part--but you could probably find an equivalent from Mill-Max or Preci-Dip or someone.

Looks similar to these pins: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/706286/old-yazaki-pcb-pins
